# Load hidden image to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, caching

I do some actions with couple of images, but to work everything smoothly I need the browser to load the images.
For example if i do 
       $('body').append('');
everything works as it should and there is no delay for loading the image.

If I try `style="display:none;"` on the image it does not load by browser and still there is a delay when executing the script.

Can you offer me any other solution? Thanks

Solution: `$('<img/>')[0].src = mouseOverImg;`
from the `Preloading images with jQuery`

Comment: try opacity instead of display?

Comment: Related: http://jakearchibald.github.io/request-quest/

Answer (score 2):

try using `visibility: hidden;` instead of `display:block;`
while `display:none;` there is no request and no space on your div for that specify image. it will only load when `display: inline;` or `display:block;`

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring with `$(document).ready(function(){ ** Your code at this place ** });`

Answer (score 0):

You may try to set its position to the off-screen.

What mean that it is is not visible for current user viewport but it was created in html.